# will it harmful for server to run a cron job in every second

Tags: php, cron, server

For the checking of online users who doesn't log out properly but close the browser, I want to run a cron job in every 2/3 second. (I am updating database in every 10 second when logged in)

Will it harmful for server?

Comment: Depends upon what you do in that cron job, but yes ***every second*** sounds like an overkill in almost every case. Plus there are much better ways to expire their sessions instead of a cron job.

Comment: Can crons be run every second? I though the lowest discrete timeframe for a cron was every minute

Comment: yes, it is possible to run cron in every second, this is not my issue. Just want to know whether it will be harmful for server performance or not?

Comment: You'd rather ask for a more elegant solution to your problem. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If you want to hammer your server with a cron job executing every second, then yes, it will severely affect the performance of your server.... every second is way too frequent for a minor housekeeping task like clearing session files

Comment: So if run cron job in every minute, will it affect server performance?

Comment: It will affect server performance, but a lot less of an overhead than every second: you manage your servers, so you're the person to identify and measure the overhead, not us.... but what you're doing is a basic housekeeping chore that should be pretty infrequent, even simple daily for many people, so even every minute feels overkill unless you have a very specific business requirement that you need to fulfil with this

Answer (score 1):

Cron lowest possible frequency is 1 minute so you cannot fire anything more often with it. As for overkill - it may or may not be there, but you need to review the code and load it produces yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run cron jobs more frequently than once a minute so this isn't possible from a cron anyways. You'd have to have a process running in a loop with sleep to achieve this, but the idea is overkill anyways - once a minute is fine.